# Should I use tsd or typings?

Tags: typescript, angular, tsd

I am wondering what is the recommended practice by Angular Team? I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs, and I am wondering what are the differences between the two. Any insights are more than welcome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tsd seems to be deprecated in favor of typings and Angular is moving to typings.

I have seen it mentioned several times that tsd is deprecated

- http://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269
- http://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6887
- http://github.com/angular/universal/issues/206
- http://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/240
- http://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/323

Comment: I noticed that too but still `typings` is not helping in install defintions for 3rd party tools like jquery! `tsd` was more helpful. what do you think?

Comment: No idea. I'm not using TS (except for Plunkers) myself - only Dart.

Answer (score 14):

It seems like the situation is changing again. From what I understand, Typescript 2.0 will use `npm` (Node Package Manager) to manage Typescript declarations for existing Javascript libraries.

The example given is that you can do:

```
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

Which will then do two things:

1. Grabs the declaration files for lodash and saves it to a directory named @types/lodash in our package's node_modules.
2. Saves that as a dependency in our package.json

For more information, please refer to this announcement from Microsoft: [The Future of Declaration Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

And also this Github issue: [Improve Declaration File Acquisition](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9184).

Comment: after tsd and typings, this is the way to go finally!

Answer (score 3):

yeah as stated in angular2's changelog from beta6
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta6-2016-02-11

- typings are no longer included in the distribution

Comment: The quote from the source is actually, "**Transitive** typings are no longer included in the distribution."